# Rotating dynamic canvas image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have the following code that allows the user to upload an image which gets put into a canvas, but once it has been drawn I want users to be able to rotate the image with the click of a button, but I don't know how to re-access the image object to be able to rotate the canvas. The code below is what works:

```
onFilePicked (e) {
  const files = e.target.files;
  for (let file of files) {
    if(file !== undefined) {
      let image = {
        thumbnail: '/img/spinner.gif'
      };
      this.images.push(image);
      this.loadImage(file, image);
    }
  }
},

loadImage(file, image) {
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.readAsDataURL(file);
  fr.addEventListener('load', () => {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = fr.result;
    img.onload = () => {
      image.thumbnail = this.resizeImage(img, 400, 300);
      image.large = this.resizeImage(img, 1280, 960);
    }        
  })
},

resizeImage(origImg, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
  let scale = 1;
  if (origImg.width > maxWidth) {
    scale = maxWidth / origImg.width;
  }
  if (origImg.height > maxHeight) {
    let scale2 = maxHeight / origImg.height;
    if (scale2 < scale) scale = scale2;
  }

  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  canvas.width = origImg.width * scale;
  canvas.height= origImg.height * scale;    
  ctx.drawImage(origImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  return canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
},
```

And seen below is the function I built out to rotate the image- it works in that if I replace the code inside of the resizeImage function with the code below that the image is drawn in a way that is rotated correctly, but I don't know how to access the origImg object to be able to redraw the canvas in a separate function.

```
rotateImage(origImg, maxWidth, maxHeight){
  let scale = 1;
  if (origImg.width > maxWidth) {
    scale = maxWidth / origImg.width;
  }
  if (origImg.height > maxHeight) {
    let scale2 = maxHeight / origImg.height;
    if (scale2 < scale) scale = scale2;
  }

  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  canvas.width = origImg.height * scale;
  canvas.height= origImg.width * scale;
  ctx.translate(canvas.width, 0);  
  ctx.rotate(90 * Math.PI / 180);
  ctx.drawImage(origImg, 0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
  return canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
},
```

Running this function as-is triggers the following console error:

Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

How do I get/reuse the origImg object from the resizeImage function so I can use it in the rotateImage function?

Comment: *I don't know how to access the origImg object to be able to redraw the canvas in a separate function.* - separate from what? You may also want to show the thing that does not work, because that is what needs fixing.

Comment: Separate from the resizeImage function. The code from the rotateImage function only works when it's inside of the resizeImage function because under those circumstances it is able to access the correct filereader image. Therefore the rotateImage function on its own does not work.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this code:

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas_id');
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(origImg,0,0); // Or at whatever offset you like
};
```

And apply your code insede onload function of img and finally transform img source to date URL

Try this code, based on one file picker, two buttons. The first one resize image and the second one rotete the image

```js
function resizeImg()
        {
        
            var oPicker = document.getElementById('avatar');
            var oImage = document.getElementById('imgOut');
            var file = oPicker.files[0];
            const fr = new FileReader();
            fr.readAsDataURL(file);
            fr.addEventListener('load', () => {
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = fr.result;
                img.onload = () => {
                  oImage.thumbnail = this.resizeImage(img, 400, 300);
                  oImage.src = this.resizeImage(img, 1280, 960);
                }        
              })
        }                
        
        function rotateImg()
        {
            var imgOut = document.getElementById('imgOut');
            
            
              let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
              let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
              let scale = 1;
              canvas.width = imgOut.height * scale;
              canvas.height= imgOut.width * scale;
              ctx.translate(canvas.width, 0);  
              ctx.rotate(90 * Math.PI / 180);
              ctx.drawImage(imgOut, 0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
              imgOut.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
              
            
        }
        
        
        function resizeImage(origImg, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
          let scale = 1;
          if (origImg.width > maxWidth) {
            scale = maxWidth / origImg.width;
          }
          if (origImg.height > maxHeight) {
            let scale2 = maxHeight / origImg.height;
            if (scale2 < scale) scale = scale2;
          }

          let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
          let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

          canvas.width = origImg.width * scale;
          canvas.height= origImg.height * scale;    
          ctx.drawImage(origImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          return canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
  </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Image test</h1>
        <img src="" id="imgOut" />
        <label for="avatar">Choose a profile picture:</label>
        <input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
        <input type="button" id="resImg" onclick="resizeImg()" value="Resize" />
        <input type="button" id="rotImg" onclick="rotateImg()" value="Rotate" />
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I updated my original question but I need to be able to trigger the rotate from a button click, so I wouldn't be able to apply that code to the onload function if I'm understanding correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a part in `onFilePicked()` where you store something about the images:

> ```
> let image = {
>   thumbnail: '/img/spinner.gif'
> };
> this.images.push(image);
> ```

and later update the same objects in `loadImage()` (well, an event handler in it) as

> ```
> image.thumbnail = this.resizeImage(img, 400, 300);
> image.large = this.resizeImage(img, 1280, 960);
> ```

It could be simply extended to

```
image.original = img;
image.thumbnail = this.resizeImage(img, 400, 300);
image.large = this.resizeImage(img, 1280, 960);
```

Starting from this point, the objects in your `images` array would have an `original` field, storing the original, non-resized variant of the image.